# Segmentation Fault in simple Sports Simulation

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm currently making a quick little text-based sports simulator. I have 2 classes so far, Team and Player. I tried making an array of Players in a team, aka a roster. (Not sure how to do it otherwise). I tried making a player and then assigning him to the first place in the roster array. It compiles fine, but when I run the program, I get the 'segmentation fault' error, which has to do with an error in memory that I've cause, I believe. The code might not be the best, so sorry if my code isn't the most optimized. If you have any suggestions on how I can fix this, let me know. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Player {
  public:
    string playerName;
    string playerAge;
    string position;
} players;

 class Team: public Player {
  public:
     string name;
     Player roster[];
 } teams;

 void teamCrocovia() {
     Team crocovia;
     crocovia.name = "ComArch Crocovia";
     Player cro1;
     crocovia.roster[0] = cro1; // This is the segmentation fault.
 }

 int main() {
     teamCrocovia();
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Team should not derive from Player.

Comment: Do not put "(Solved)" in your title. We can tell when an answer has been accepted without that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot expect this:

```
Player roster[];                 // this is a zero-sized array
```

to be a variable-sized array (no such thing in C++) and add elements like:

```
crocovia.roster[0]               // out of bounds access
```

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<Player> roster;      // in Team
crocovia.roster.push_back(cro1); // add player
```

Also, I don't get why `Team` inherits from `Player` and you're immediately creating objects with plural names of each class, that are not even used.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry if my code seems really 'nooby'.

Comment: Would you be willing to possibly show a replacement of my code using std::vector? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Again, sorry if my code uses some naive stuff, I'm still learning. Thank you.

Comment: That's OK, but do something about what I said in the last sentence.

Comment: So now how do I reference 'cro1' like printing it's name?

Comment: That you do the same way as with an array. But get a C++ book or find a tutorial if you don't have time.

Answer (score 3):

You should define the size of the array, for example

```
Player roster[5];
```

If when you're writing the code you don't know for sure the size of the array, 
you should just declare it as

```
Player *roster;
```

and somewhere else (preferably in the constructor of class Team) actually
make it an array, maybe like this

```
roster = new Player[k];
```

, where k is the number of players you want in the team.

Also, about this

```
 class Team: public Player
```

I don't think that is what you want.
I dont think you want to declare that Team IS A Player.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll be trying out the answer above yours, using vectors, but thanks for taking the time to answer.